# Faster way to download pages using curl?

Tags: php, curl, data-mining

Hi,

I download a large amount of files for data mining. I used to use PHP for this purpose but I am finding it to be too slow. Also I just want a small part of the web page. I want to achieve two things

1. Curl should be able to utilize all my download bandwidth
2. Is there any way to download only a part of the web page where my data resides.

I am not confined to PHP. If curl works better in terminal I would use that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can download only a part of the page by using the CURLOPT_RANGE option, and you can also provide a write callback function that simply returns an error when you've received "enough" data and you want to stop and move on.

Comment: thanks a lot can you please explain how can i put this option in php

Comment: A little help for it might be found in the original libcurl documentation for the option:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTRANGE

Answer (score 0):

Are you downloading HTML? Your comment leads me to believe that you are. If that's the case, simply load up the html with Simple PHP DOM and get only the part that you want. Although, I find it hard to believe that grabbing just the HTML is slowing you down. Are you downloading any files or media as well?

Link : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to download only part of a page. When you request a URL, the server response is what it is.

Utilize more of your bandwidth by using cURL's ability to make [multiple connections at once](http://www.google.com/q=curl+multiple+connections).

Comment: this is wrong, HTTP offers a range header for exactly this purpose